# How to use Facebook authentication in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

I'm a beginner in Laravel. I just want to make `Facebook Authentication System` in my website. I already use `Socialize` in my project. I successfully retrieve facebook's user information in facebook callback function , but I tried to pass information to register and login request in laravel authentication.

Below is my `facebook_callback` function code.

```
function facebook_callback()
{
    $user = Socialize::with('facebook')->user();
    $registerCtrl = new RegisterController;
    $loginCtrl = new LoginController;

    $email = $user->getEmail();

    // Check if alredy registered
    $member = User::where('email','=',$email)->first();
    if($member===null){
        // Register user
        $nameArray = explode(" ",$user->getName()); 
        $fname = $nameArray[0];
        $lname = $nameArray[1];
        $password = $user->getId();

        $request = Request::create('/register','POST',array(
            "_token" => Session::token(),
            "fname" =>  $fname,
            "lname" =>  $lname,
            "email" =>  $email,
            "password" =>  $password,
            "password_confirmation" =>  $password
        ));
        $registerCtrl->register($request);
    }
    else{
        // Login user
        $password = $user->getId();

        $request = Request::create('/login','POST',array(
            "_token" => Session::token(),
            "email" =>  $email,
            "password" =>  $password
        ));
        $loginCtrl->login($request);
    }
    // $response = Route::dispatch($request);
    return redirect('/home');
}
```

I can register , but when I tried to login I got this error.

[image: Click here to see my error image]

Comment: Check any setting to redirect url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already solved problem , just use Auth($user) for login. So below is my code.

```
function facebook_callback()
{

    $socialUser = Socialize::with('facebook')->user();
    $registerCtrl = new RegisterController;
    $email = $socialUser->getEmail();

    if($email==null){
        // User not allowed to use email
        if($this->checkExistUserByFacebookID($socialUser->id)==true){
            // Login user
            $user = User::where('email','=',$socialUser->id)->first();
            Auth::login($user);
        }
        else{
            // Register user first
            $nameArray = explode(" ",$socialUser->getName()); 
            $fname = $nameArray[0];
            $lname = $nameArray[1];
            $password = $socialUser->getId();
            $request = Request::create('/register','POST',array(
                "_token" => Session::token(),
                "fname" =>  $fname,
                "lname" =>  $lname,
                "email" =>  $socialUser->id,
                "password" =>  $password,
                "password_confirmation" =>  $password
            ));
            $registerCtrl->register($request);
        }
    }
    else{
        // User allowed to use email
        if($this->checkExistUserByEmail($socialUser->email)==true){
            // Login user
            $user = User::where('email','=',$email)->first();
            Auth::login($user);

        }
        else{
            // Register user first
            $nameArray = explode(" ",$socialUser->getName()); 
            $fname = $nameArray[0];
            $lname = $nameArray[1];
            $password = $socialUser->getId();
            $request = Request::create('/register','POST',array(
                "_token" => Session::token(),
                "fname" =>  $fname,
                "lname" =>  $lname,
                "email" =>  $email,
                "password" =>  $password,
                "password_confirmation" =>  $password
            ));
            $registerCtrl->register($request);
        }
    }
    return redirect('/home');
}
```

Thanks you Riyan Sheikh for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

For Laravel 5.2 or 5.3: You need to use the web middleware if you need session state, CSRF protection, and more.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    // your routes here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your above code is ok. If still not work then please check your kernel.php file. Add below code in kernel.php

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\UserVerificationChecker::class
        ],
];
```

Comment: I already solved problem , just use Auth($user) for login. So below is my code.